# How to take backup of a table on a different schema in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-14.04, command

Please let us know in PostgreSQL how we can take backup of a table on a different schema. We have db named "geopostgrest" and under Schema named "1" (Not inside Public Schema) we need to take backup of table "activity"

Please see the following:

```
postgres=# \c geopostgrest
You are now connected to database "geopostgrest" as user "postgres".
geopostgrest=# \dt
No relations found.
geopostgrest=# \dt 1.
                      List of relations
 Schema |              Name               | Type  |  Owner
--------+---------------------------------+-------+----------
 1      | activity                        | table | postgres
```

We tried the following command but its not working.

```
pg_dump -U postgres -n1 -d geopostgrest -t activity  -f activity_05-08-2015.sql

pg_dump: No matching tables were found
```

We are using PostgreSQL 9.4.4 and Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS

Can any one please help us on it

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Able to take backup of a table on a different schema in PostgreSQL with the following command and its working perfectly:

```
pg_dump -U postgres -t 1.activity -d geopostgrest -f activity_05-08-2015.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with `-n 1` (space between them)?

Also I cannot find the `-d` parameter. If you need to specify the database then you just put it in as the last or first parameter.

Comment: Yes tried but getting same error `pg_dump: No matching tables were found`